# Youtube Data API v3 - Disable playlist controls

Tags: php, html, youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently creating this website that has a space for a 200x200 video player only, so I need to reduce the amount of clutter there is on the "video control panel". 
This is how the Player looks like right now, I need to remove the `|<` & `>|` buttons
[image]

Thanks!

Snippet:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list={PLAYLISTIDHERE}" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on your code, but you can try "controls=0", as in:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/$VIDEOID?controls=0
where you replace $VIDEOID with a valid video ID.

Note, that this will also remove the slider to go forward and backward within the video during playing.
To remove also the related videos at the end, after playing, add the parameter "rel=0", as in:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/$VIDEOID?controls=0&rel=0

See for a list of available parameters:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Try:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?controls=0&listType=playlist&list={PLAYLISTIDHERE}" />
```

Seems the playlist selection does show at left top corner but is not working anymore with controls=0.

An option might be to use autohide=1. I also added modestbranding=1 as suggested.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?modestbranding=1&autohide=1&listType=playlist&list={PLAYLISTIDHERE}" />
```

Comment: It won't work, I've added the snippet Im using to the main post, see that. It's a playlist Im working with

Comment: You should show your snippet with "controls=0" already added. It must be part of the src string. I just added a snippet to my answer.

Comment: I do see a problem. The controls at the bottom are gone. But the playlist selection at the left top corner don't work anymore, although it is still visible.

Comment: Added a snippet. using autohide.

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible. However you can remove the youtube logo on the playerbar to get some room.
Add the parameter modestbranding=1 to your request

Example http://www.youtube.com/embed/KMoWVujxJgg?modestbranding=1